# potentiometer as voltage divider and taper

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

assuming that I'm going to change the potentiometer value (now is 50K linear) to 100K linear, should I also change the value for R1 and R2 in order to keep the same taper and the same power consumption as the 50K potentiometer?
I guess R1 is there to provide a more reverse log response

[image]

Comment: R2 cannot be determined because you don't show where it connects.

Comment: R1 yes. R2 may be satisfactory as-is, depending on what's off to the right we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you must increase R1 to maintain the same taper.  But as above, the final effective taper depends on the current through R2, and that depends on the impedance of whatever device or circuit is connected to it.

Comment: Assuming the impedance of the circuit connected to it is the same as when using 50K, should I decrease R2 as I increase R1?

Comment: Again, that depends on what the impedance of that circuit is, compared to the equivalent resistances of the pot at, say, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% rotation.  Since you said you wanted to keep the same (effective) taper, that means you want the same output voltage for any particular rotation.  But the output voltage is determined in part by the voltage divider of R2 and the downstream impedance.  The voltage at the right side of R2 cannot be predicted without knowing what R2 goes to.